# Definition of 'Identity'

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, terminology, definitions

This may seem like a very specific or stupid question, but I'm new to this, I'm interested in the idea of 'identity' and 'identical. I've heard some description of the idea different 'copies' or instances of numbers (I'm currently exploring this idea, I'm aware some don't think of it this way, and that it is a very complex issue) in some perspectives be written as being 'qualitatively identical' but not 'numerically identical', this seems counter-intuitive as they must be equal, and hence they must be 'numerically identical'. If we use the equals sign to be Mathematically correct, the 'copies' on either side must be 'Numerically identical' and hence one and the same, I wonder if perhaps my concept of both is incorrect?

Comment: It is mathematically correct to use the = sign for any equivalence relation, the two sides need to match only in some precisely specified respects, not be even qualitatively, let alone numerically identical. Mathematics is a science of form only, not metaphysical substance, what different instances of 1 metaphysically are makes no difference as long as they are subjected to the same formal rules. There is a nice discussion of identity of numbers in [Shapiro's Philosophy of Mathematics, pp. 77-84](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Philosophy_of_Mathematics/9xVErjy9qPQC?hl=en&gbpv=0).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is identity defined in the law of identity A = A?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/82041/how-is-identity-defined-in-the-law-of-identity-a-a). There are many other questions on identity on this site, please take some time to search, find the one that is closest to your interest, and ask again relating to that question about what you want to know additionally.

Comment: Using Frege's example, Hesperus is the same planet as Phosphorus so clearly we have Hesperus = Phosphorus. But on the other hand the two sides contain totally different senses, so seems not exactly identical in all aspects. A paradox? Is your confusion about the definition of identity similar?

Comment: It is quite complex... You can see the new perspective on *identity* due to [Martin-Löf type theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory-intuitionistic/) and more specifically [Ansten Klev's research](https://www.researchgate.net/scientific-contributions/Ansten-Klev-2119965326)

Comment: See also the post [Does the sentence "prove that two things are equal" has a sense?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4165338/does-the-sentence-prove-that-two-things-are-equal-has-a-sense)

Comment: Ok cheers I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Identity is actually a complex concept.

Liebniz suggested a metaphysical principle of the identity of indiscernables. This principle says that if all the properties of two objects are the same they are identical.

This is modified in modern mathematics where it is affirmed not that they are identical but that they are isomorphic. Here, isomorphic is the mathematical translation of the notion of being indiscernable. This view is taken as a principle in Category Theory.

This view is important in the intuitionistic development of calculus where an infinitesimal is indiscernable from zero, yet not not identical to it. For this to be true, we have to modify the underlying logic from classical to intuitionistic by dropping the law of the excluded middle.

So whilst contra Liebniz's view,  two things that are qualitatively alike may not be same thing.

Answer (score -1):

Mathematics is necessarily and intentionally abstract. When we start to disentangle the abstractions, we find that the notion of identity has two distinct meanings. For instance the equation '1 = 1' can be understood as either of the following:

- **Numeric equivalence**: 1 (object of a class) = 1 (different object of the same class). E.g., '1 apple = 1 apple' and '1 orange = 1 orange', but '1 apple ≠ 1 orange'.
- **Reflexive reference**: 1 (object) = (itself). There's no digit on the righthand side because (like a pointer in software) the digit is carried across in the act of self-reference.

There are no 'copies' or 'instances' of numbers here, because numbers aren't the objects involved. They are *quantifiers* for the implied objects. They serve roughly the same purpose as adjectives in language, modifying something that (in this case) no one has bothered to specify.

I mean, consider an English sentence like:

> A perceptive student is a great asset.

Now we take out the nouns and get:

> A perceptive is a great.

and we can break that further into two statements:

> A is A

and...

> perceptive is great

The first is the abstract mathematical statement: '1 = 1', the second an abstract associative implication that the quality 'perceptive' suggests the quality 'great'. The first is *math*, the second *logic*. These are not properly-formed sentences in their own right, but are mere shorthand for a set of arbitrary sentences that fit the format.

Now, the nice thing about quantitative modifiers is that they obey distinct and well-defined rules, so long as the objects they abstractly refer to are immiscible (meaning they remain separate when put together: 1 apple + 1 apple = 2 apples because apples don't merge; 1 water + 1 water is undefined, because it depends on the container(s) used). The downside is that — partly because of this obedience to rules — people tend to objectify the adjective. I mean we all see the grammatical/logical  error if say:

> We can have a **perceptive** subject, so what exactly is a 'perceptive'?

But it somehow seems more reasonable with quantifiers, e.g.:

> We can have **three** subjects, so what exactly is a 'three'?

But does 'three' really have more claim to object-hood that 'perceptive'? I'd suggest not; it's just a trick of the language game we play when we abstract quantificational adjectives into mathematics.

Answer (score -2):

In so far as mathematics (whatever it might be) is not logic (whatever it might be), the two must relate in such a way that the sign of equality is the "first" symbol of a mathematical language. This is because the sign of equality governs substitution of syntactic expressions.

In contrast with portrayals of mathematics declaring reflexive equality statements to be necessarily true, Augustus de Morgan recognized that the sign of equality could not be purely formal. Substitutivity requires a warrant.

Analytical philosophy treats reflexive equality statements as necessarily true because different occurrences of the same symbol should denote uniformly. Consequently, they should be substitutable for one another. This is essentially justified by an analytical conception of truth whereby truth is invested in word  meanings (whatever that might mean).

A semantic conception of truth, however, does not entail the necessary truth of reflexive equality statements. If two occurrences of a term in a reflexive equality statement do not denote, there is no justification for claiming it to be true. Tyler Burge's paper on truth and singular terms is one place to find a discussion of this. This relates to definedness in ordinary mathematics. The issue comes up in mathematical logic through recursion theory in which a special symbol must be introduced admitting undefined expressions as arguments.

Declarations of "what mathematics is" often ignore minor details such as the undecidability of equality in views of mathematics which are not realist. You can find papers on equality in the presence of apartness in terms of modal semantics (Statman and van Dalen) and in terms of proof theory (Boretti and Negri). So, perform due diligence with respect to the easy answers you receive.

One problem presented by language is the expectation that terms like names denote singularly. In logics that manage existential import as opposed to assuming it, denial of an informative equality can mean either a plurality or non-existence. So, the relationship with distinctness cannot be classical bivalence. In so far as distinctness means that no terms can be found which could co-refer, denying distinctness means that two terms can co-satisfy.

The problem is whether or not two terms may justifiably be treated as one thing. An axiom can assert their substitutivity in a logical calculus. But, an axiom cannot assert an objectual ontology.

The alternative to objectual ontology is differential ontology. It is relevant to historical debate by virtue of the fact that Kant's criticism of the principle of the identity of indiscernibles had emphasized numerical difference in spatial terms (apartness). By contrast, modern debate on the principle of the identity of indiscernibles has emphasized numerical identity in spatial terms (Wittgenstein TLP 3.144: names resemble points).

Both are problematic. In his book on individuals, Strawson has a significant passage which uses a geometric diagram to explain how qualitative identity fails to convey numerical identity. This passage is particularly good because it includes dialectical discussion of the kind of skeptical arguments which would have one believing that the whole universe could change if one blinks. More importantly, it also discusses how there is a circularity between points of space and parts of space. That is, points differentiate parts and parts separate points. Numerical identity on the basis of naive geometric notions of the indivisibility of points yields the problem of transcendence to completed infinities (limit ordinals, cardinals, and inaccessibles to be precise).

Numerical difference, however, leads to the kind of regress which foundationalist demand for objectual ontology seeks to deny. The problem is that this foundationalist demand is only accomplished through dogmatic stipulation. Those who would promote certain claims about "what mathematics is" tend to portray this dogmatic stipulation as being equivalent with the kind of stipulative definition found in ordinary mathematics. But, since it leads to consequences which fail to respect ordinary mathematical practices, it is not convincing to many practicing mathematicians.

Once one learns to speak of equality in all cases, then identity can be recognized as a philosophical concept that provides a substitutivity warrant for one way of studying mathematics.

It is not--- and should never be portrayed as--- the single correct way of studying mathematics. The necessary truth of reflexive equality statements is necessary to logicist mathematics in order to derive the symmetry of identity from the principle of indiscernibility of identicals. Actually doing the proof is the best way to understand why identity is not merely an equivalence relation. The symmetry of identity must be proven.

Note the use of a plural in the phrase "indiscernibility of identicals." That is one reason equality is hard in logic. Do not let anyone convince you otherwise.

One of Alfred Tarski's projects had been cylindric algebra. It is an algebraic approach to first-order logic  William Lawvere, a category theorist who maintains that philosophy turned away from standard mathematics long ago, points to cylindric algebra as a more mathematical understanding of logic. If one examines the axioms of cylindric algebra, the transitivity axiom stands out.

One finds an existential quantifier embedded within the transitivity axiom for cylindric algebra. If one forms the free algebra over this axiom, one will generate a countably infinite number of singular terms which would all be substitutable for one another.

It is very difficult to actually make uses of the equality symbol comply with the intended "oneness" we ascribe to names and singular terms.

As for the link leading to the explanation of a unique relation an object has with itself, the paper by Burge is one place to find someone who is not impressed with such an explanation.

You might find Max Black's paper on the identity of indiscernibles interesting along with the book "Understanding Identity Statements" by Thomas Morris. In addition, the nature of identity is central to debate over definite descriptions. This will include works by Frege, Russell, Wittgenstein, Strawson, Davidson, Lambert, and Neale.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the arrow to reward the contributor and the checkmark to select what you feel is the best answer.

Comment: +1 Thoroughness!

Comment: And 'whatever it be' is one of my favorite qualifiers. :D